# Objective-C calling instance method within Singleton

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created a Singleton class named `DataManager`. I've set up some caching. However, when attempting to call the cache instance methods from within another instance method of `DataManager`, I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the line:

```
NSMutableArray *stops = [[DataManager sharedInstance] getCacheForKey:@"stops"];
```

**DataManager.h**

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject {
    FMDatabase *db;
    NSMutableDictionary *cache;
}

+ (DataManager *)sharedInstance;
// ... more methods
- (id)getCacheForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (void)setCacheForKey:(NSString *)key withValue:(id)value;
- (void)clearCache;
```

**DataManager.m**

```
- (NSArray *)getStops:(NSInteger)archived {
    NSMutableArray *stops = [[DataManager sharedInstance] getCacheForKey:@"stops"];
    if (stops != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Stops: %@", stops);
        return stops;
    }

    stops = [NSMutableArray array];
    // set stops...

    [[DataManager sharedInstance] setCacheForKey:@"stops" withValue:stops];

    return stops;
}
```

It seems to occur when called from another view controller. That is the first view controller no error, second view controller, error.

This is my first attempt at a Singleton, so I'm sure I am making a simple mistake. But I am failing to see it myself.

**Note:** I've tried `[self getCache...]` with the same result.

#### UPDATE

Here is my Singleton implementation. Adapted from http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

```
+ (DataManager *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [[self sharedInstance] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;
}

- (oneway void)release {
    // never release
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {        
        if (db == nil){
            BourbonAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BourbonAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
            db = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:[appDelegate getDBPath]];
        }

        if (![db open]) {
            NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database.");
            [db release];

            return nil;
        }

        [db setTraceExecution:YES];        
        [db setLogsErrors:TRUE];

        cache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSLog(@"cache: %@", cache);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize your singleton?

Comment: In the class method `sharedInstance`.

Comment: Show your implementation of `sharedInstance` and `setCacheForKey:withValue:`. The code you are showing looks fine, even though you just should use `self` instead of the `sharedInstance` method inside your instance methods.

Comment: I got a very similar error when I first tried to create a singleton. It wasnt implemented correctly. Can you post your init and sharedInstance methods?

Comment: `getCacheForKey:` should just be `cacheForKey:`.  Cocoa/iOS does not use the `get` prefix for getters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `cache` object is autoreleased, so it's no longer in memory when you try to access it.

Use `[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` instead of `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` to get an instance that is retained.

Comment: Or make cache a retained property

Comment: Doh. Make sense. Begs another question though. How do I properly release it as `dealloc` is theoretically never called?

Comment: Well, you don't. It is a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your question, which was already answered.

However I'd just like to point out that your singleton implementation is sub-optimal. `@synchronized` is very expensive, and you can avoid using it every time you access the singleton:

```
if (!instance) {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }
}
```

An even better way to initialize a singleton would be:

```
+ (DataManager *)sharedInstance {
    static DataManager *instance;

    static dispatch_once_t donce;
    dispatch_once(&donce, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I read that before. However, was unsure if this is okay when I'm supporting iOS 4+?

Comment: Not sure about 4.0+, but I can guarantee 4.2+. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely keep that in mind for future apps that support 4.2+.